# Setting up New Relic for Django development server

Tags: django, newrelic

I am using Django and trying out New Relic. Is it possible to monitor the Django development server? I can only seem to find help on setting up New Relic with production servers.

### Edit

'How to' for future reference:

(I used Django1.4)

1. Follow this:
   https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-installation
2. As the last step of that guide (*Integration with your Application*) change your `wsgi.py` file to the following:

   ```
   import newrelic.agent

   newrelic.agent.initialize('/home/username/path/to/myproject/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic.ini')

   import os
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

   application = get_wsgi_application()
   application = newrelic.agent.wsgi_application()(application)
   ```

Now sign in to your account on the New Relic platform, make a few requests to your development server and see the changes on the the platform. Grats, you made it!

Comment: @Alasdair ```newrelic.agent.initialize('/home/username/path/to/myproject/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic.ini')``` newrelic.ini is supposed to be present int the python executable location right? Not sure if this is obsolete now.

Comment: @Atom The `newrelic.agent.initialize()` line was added by Bentley4 *after* I answered the question, so I can't help with that. If you're stuck, I would ask a new question instead of adding comments to a 6 year old question.

Comment: I got it to working. I have to point it to the newrelic.ini present in the python executable location. Thanks @Alasdair

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Django 1.4, the startproject command [creates a wsgi file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/#the-application-object) that the `runserver` command will use.

If you have an older Django project that does not have a wsgi file, you can create one as described in the Django docs, and set [`WSGI_APPLICATION`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application) in your `settings.py` file.

You should be able to set up new relic by modifying this wsgi file as described by the New Relic docs for [Python agent integration](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-integration#manual-integration).